# Criar banco de dados sem Migration no Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação de estudo em Entity Framework Core, e vi que através do code-first é possível gerar o banco de dados usando o comando add-migration, mas gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma da aplicação criar a base de dados sem que exista a necessidade de eu executar os comandos add-migration e update-database.

Gostaria de fazer algo semelhante ao hibernate, onde toda vez que executo a aplicação ele atualiza a base de acordo com as anotações das entidades.

Answer (score 3):

Sim, é possível!

**EF**

1 - Inicialização do DBContext, executa antes de instanciar o Context.

```
Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<YourDbContext, YourMigrationConfiguration>());
```

2 - Classe de configuração

```
public class YourMigrationConfiguration<TContext> : DbMigrationsConfiguration<TContext> 
    where TContext  : DbContext{

    protected  YourMigrationConfiguration() {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;  // Executa sem esperar os comandos do PM
        AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;

    }
```

3 - Context.Database.Initialize(true);

http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/database-initialization-strategy-in-code-first.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621

---

**EF Core**

No caso do EF Core voce precisa fazer a seguinte configuração na sua Startup.cs ou no inicializador do seu contexto.

```
public class DBInitialization
{
    public static void Initialize()
    {
        using (var context = new DbContext())
        {
            context.Database.Migrate();

            // Other db initialization code.
        }
    }
}
```

---

**EF Core - First Data Seed**

Crio uma classe de extensão com 2 métodos, o primeiro para verificar se todos os Migrations foram aplicados e em seguida crio o método Seed verificando se cada Entidade a ser inicializada está vazia inserindo então as informações necessárias.

```
public static class ContextExtensions
{

    public static bool MigrationsApplied(this DbContext context)
    {
        var applied = context.GetService<IHistoryRepository>()
            .GetAppliedMigrations()
            .Select(m => m.MigrationId);

        var total = context.GetService<IMigrationsAssembly>()
            .Migrations
            .Select(m => m.Key);

        return !total.Except(applied).Any();
    }

    public static void Seed(this DbContext context)
    {

        if (!context.Model1.Any())
        {
            var model = new Model1 { Name = "Teste" };

            context.Add(model);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }

        if (!context.Status.Any())
        {
            var status = new Status { Name = "Ativo" };
            context.AddRange(stati);
            context.SaveChanges();

        }
    }
}
```

No arquivo Startup no método Configure, faço a inicialização aplicando o Migrate e depois faço o Seed.

```
            using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
            {
                if (!serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<MyContext>().MigrationsApplied())
                {
                    serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<MyContext>().Database.Migrate();
                    serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<MyContext>().Seed();
}
            }
```

Comment: Mas isso seria para o Entity Framework Core?

Comment: No caso do EF Core vc pode context.Database.Migrate().

Comment: atualizei o exemplo, veja se te ajuda! :)

Comment: Para tirar 10, pode adicionar sample de *first data seed*?

Comment: @ThiagoLunardi sinceramente não sei se é a forma mais adequada, mas o que faço é um método de extensão para validar se tudo foi migrado com sucesso em seguida faço o Migrate e Seed.

Comment: Sim, se for a primeira criação, é o sistema depender de dados iniciais/mínimos para funcionar, é o que há de mais adequado. Ex. Na primeira execução do WordPress, ele cria um usuário admin padrão e uma categoria Default.

Comment: @ThiagoLunardi da uma olhada no exemplo, é só uma ideia!

Comment: Show! É assim que se faz!!!