# erro conexao sql

Tags: .net, asp.net, connectionstring

Boa noite,

Estou tentando efetuar um cadastro em minha aplicação, porém está me retornando o seguinte erro:

> Erro de rede ou específico à instância ao estabelecer conexão com o SQL Server. O servidor não foi encontrado ou não estava acessível. Verifique se o nome da instância está correto e se o SQL Server está configurado para permitir conexões remotas. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Ocorreu um erro de Local Database Runtime. Não é possível criar uma instância automática. Consulte o log de eventos do Aplicativo do Windows para obter detalhes do erro.

no trecho de código:

```
var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
```

Minha string de conexao:

```
connectionString="Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=Inventario;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=minhasenha
```

Consigo conectar normalmente no meu banco, pelo teste de conexão pela aplicação tb passa o teste, alguem sabe o que pode ser ?

Desde ja agradeço.

Comment: Eu costumo utilizar "Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB" para conectar ao banco local

Comment: nada, da o mesmo erro

Comment: Você está utilizando entity framework? conseguiu fazer as migrações?

Comment: sim estou usando entity, nao estou utilizando migrations.

Comment: E como você criou as tabelas no banco?

Comment: pelo managment studio conecta normalmente?

Comment: sim, ele nao cria o banco automaticamente após vc conectar a primeira vela pela aplicação? ou tenho sempre que usar o migrations ?

Comment: não é obrigatório o uso de migrations manual, olha só o post que acabei de responder mostrando como criar o banco sem comando do migrations: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/221186/criar-banco-de-dados-sem-migration-no-entity-framework-core/221200#221200